# Automatic update to 3.1.0 beta (2014-03-28 r65330) on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, package-management, apt, r

I am re-asking this question on behalf of ECII who originally asked it on stackoverflow but which got shut down: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760473/automatic-update-to-3-1-0-beta-2014-03-28-r65330-on-ubuntu-12-04

The problem is as follows:

Ubuntu 12.04 machines are getting their installation of R automatically updated to 3.1.0 beta (2014-03-28 r65330), even without nightly repos, e.g. http://cran.at.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu precise . This is a major problem for me as it means all the packages are now broken and I cannot install any new packages via install.packages. What is going on?

Why did that happen? R 3.1 is not even released? Is it a CRAN bug?

P.s. even the workarounds do not seem to work - e.g.

```
apt-cache showpkg r-base 
sudo apt-get install -f r-base-core=3.0.3-1precise0 - correct version
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently its a human error. 
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2014-April/002251.html

I have found no workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to downgrade to any 3.0.x rev and reliably install all the packages in r-recommended. It looks like they have decided to punt since R 3.1 is released tomorrow:

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.debian/2205